# What is the correct way to remove files from hg repo after stripping?

Tags: mercurial

I have, by mistake, added a large file to hg repo. I then stripped the changeset, but noticed that the repo size (.hg folder size) hasn't decreased. I've done `hg convert <old_repo> <new_repo>`, and the size did decrease. So it sort of works for me, but I'd like to understand the concept.

What is the purpose of keeping the files in the repo if they are not in history anymore?

Is my method of deleting files from the history the best practice (forgetting that I shouldn't be adding them in the first place)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this may be the cause:

When you strip a changeset, mercurial will create a bundle of the change and place it in .hg/strip-backup directory. This allows you recover the changeset using the hg unbundle command.

This can make the size of .hg appear unchanged. This file can be deleted if you do not intent to restore from it and the size of .hg should reflect this.

Note: strip will print the name of the bundle file it creates. You can also tell strip to not create the bundle file with the --no-backup option.

Comment: This is really nice! I am using TortoiseHg, and don't usually read the console output. So I had no chance of noticing the filename. And I simply didn't think that the "no-backup" option being unchecked should lead to backup creation. Thanks for the nice explanation!

Comment: Glad it help you

Comment: Note to readers --  if you were to clone a repo which had all these backups, the clone would show the smaller file size.